# Класс не имеет атрибут при помещении в блок исключений

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, pyqt5, классы

При помещении в исключение вида `try / except` класс не видит атрибут `item_price`. При удалении `try / except` все отрабатывает как и должно.

Некоторая часть кода с исключением:

```
Class View(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    ...

    def get_data(self):
        try:
            self.item_price = [[self.data[0]['city'], self.data[0]['sell_price']]]
        except IndexError:
           pass
        return self.item_price
.....
```

Исключение вызывается при `return self.item_price`:

> AttributeError: 'View' object has no attribute 'item_price'

Comment: Ну тогда просто удалите try/except

Comment: @andreymal Без него нельзя так как это 'сборщик' и он просто проверяет наличие и если нет переходит дальше.

Comment: Ну так если наличие не подтвердилось, то и дальше перейти очевидно невозможно, ведь требуемого наличия нет. Определитесь с тем, что вы вообще хотите

Comment: Переход дальше возможен вернет просто пустой список. А на это у меня уже есть определенные механизмы.

Comment: Ну вот и возвращайте пустой список, зачем вы пытаетесь возвращать несуществующий `item_price` вместо этого?

Comment: Ну а вообще да, добавлять поля объекту не в конструкторе — плохой тон, лучше сделать как S. Nick предлагает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Объявите `self.item_price` в конструкторе:

```
class View(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.item_price = []     # <----- или None
        
    ...   

def get_data(self):
    try:
        self.item_price = [[self.data[0]['city'], self.data[0]['sell_price']]]
    except IndexError:
       pass
       
    return self.item_price
```

...

---

или так

```
class View(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    ...    
        

    def get_data(self):
        try:
            self.item_price = [[self.data[0]['city'], self.data[0]['sell_price']]]
        except IndexError:
           self.item_price = []                       # <----
           
        return self.item_price                       
...
```

Comment: Первый вариант. Хорошо отрабатывает.